# Python script - how to pass password as variable from command line arguments

Tags: python, variables, command, line

I am running a REST call using python to generate a access token.
The REST call payload has password value.
I dont want to hardcode the password there but pass it as an option while running the python script. Below is the payload inside the python script.

```
payload = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=userid&client_secret=password&scope=AppIdClaimsTrust&intent=RequestLink"
```

Currently I exectute the script by **python script.py**

Comment: Have you done any research on how to pass a command-line value into a program? Have you looked at [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html)? Also, clarify if you want the password to be passed as an option when the script is started (which `argparse` handles) or while the script is already running?

Comment: I did and I saw some examples too. However I could not implement them in my script successfully. Hence throught will ask the question here expecting a direct answer (which I got already).

Comment: They question asked could have been better structured. But the content in the discussion is interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the token as an environment variable:

`$ export TOKEN=XXXXXXX`

Then using the `os` library:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os

token = os.environ['TOKEN']
```

Use `token` where you would normally hard code it into your script.

Alternatively, you could pass it as a [command line argument](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm).

```
$ python script.py XXXXXXXX
```

In your script, access the token using:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    token = sys.argv[1]
else:
    print("No token passed")
```

Comment: That worked.  But cant we pass it through command line? something like "python script.py passwordvalue"

Comment: I edited the post while you were writing that comment. Use `sys.argv`

Comment: I made 1 more edit to the post. This edit ensures you won't have an out of bounds exception if no argument is passed to the function.

Comment: One more question, I saw some one using it like "python script.py --arg1 "value" --arg2 "value" Can you also please help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this using [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sys.html#sys.argv). This provides a list of arguments passed to the script, of which `sys.argv[0]` is the script name (or "-c"). You can access the first argument with `sys.argv[1]` although it's often better to do some error checking to make sure you actually get what you want. I would often do something like:

```
import sys
args = sys.argv
if args[1]:
    password = args[1]
```

You can also use a more robust parser such as [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/argparse.html?highlight=argparse#module-argparse).